# Angular: Consequence of Import into multiple component/module into standalone component?

Tags: angular, module, architecture

So,

I've migrated to Angular 16 and decide to migrate a good number of my components from NGModule to standalone component.

By doing so, I've realized a lot of them where importating the sames things.
Of Course, there is ng-if "@angular/common", but also somes angular material element.

This is where i've somes questions.

1. Does the multiplication of imports through several components have any consequences (duplication of code during generation / useless/duplicate imports when loading a component)?
2. For the most recurrent imports (sometimes in a hundred or so components), is there a suitable way of centralizing them to improve performance and/or readability?
   If so, which?

By Exemple, if i've 30 components, each one with an imported "FormsModule" and "MatSidenavModule" . Should I just centralize the import of FormModule and MatSidenavModule into an NgModule, then import this Module into the standalone components ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: ` Should I just centralize the import`: that's up to you.  How angular loads in the resources in the memory may have changed in the years but the concept is still a singleton pattern. X number of components that use the same - for example - `FormsModule` don't generate X number references of that module; so it is memory safe. For point 2: Standalone components are that, standalone. They require their own imports. You can't really centralize the import but if you have the same X modules imported in each component then you should create a custom `ngModule` and import that instead.

Comment: @JacopoSciampi Thanks, it was the doubt i had and wanted to make sure of it